# Reassign event callback after first execution

Tags: jquery, callback

### Question

How can one reassign a jQuery event handler callback after it's first execution?

### Why?

If you've ever built a fancy interface using the DOM and jQuery, you know you used that cool `fadeIn()` method on items that are set to `display: none` in the CSS. So the natural check, everytime you run something against that DOM element that is set to not display is to first check if it is visible. You'll probably use something like this:

```
if (!$('#some-element').is(":visible"))
```

And you put that in your event handler callback and then whole thing would end up looking something like this:

```
$('.clickers').on('click', function() {
    if (!$('#some-element').is(":visible")) {
        $('#some-element').fadeIn('slow'); //Slow because we're cool
    }

    //do everything else
})
```

Well if `#some-element` isn't supposed to disappear after that, you still have this unnecessary if statement that checks if it's visible, even though WE already know it is.

### Solution? Maybe

The two best possible solution I have thought of so far:

#### First

The first involves reassigning the function by using `off()` on the event handler and then another `on()` which will execute after the first time the item is clicked (or the event occurs, whatever that may be):

```
$('.clicker').on('click',function() {
    if (!$('#some-element').is(':visible')) {
        $('#some-element').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    $('#some-element').html("I was clicked: " + $(this).text());
    $('.clicker').off('click').on('click', function() {
        $('#some-element').html("I was clicked: " + $(this).text());
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gyqx9/)

I don't like this because of the `off() on()` chain. That's a lot of work, especially if there are a lot of the same class items to handle the event (all to avoid a simple if statement). I also don't like it because the function could get complicated, which would have to be duplicated in the second callback assignment.

#### Second

The second solution is to put the call back in a separate function, and then reassign the function:

```
$('.clicker').on('click', function () {
    callback.call(this, $('#some-element'));
    callback = function (display) {
        display.html("I was clicked: " + $(this).text());
    }
    callback.call(this, $('#some-element'));
});

var callback = function (display) {
    if (!display.is(':visible')) {
        display.fadeIn('slow');
    }
    display.html("I was clicked: " + $(this).text());
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gyqx9/1/)

I don't like this for the same exact reason as the first one where what if the function is something longer. Is this as good as it gets? Is there a better way to do this to get away from the two issues I have with my implementations?

Comment: If the element is already visible, then `.fadeIn` doesn't do anything I believe, so the check is unnecessary (of course `.fadeIn` will do the check internally.

Comment: @FelixKling, Ok, bad example. I'll think of something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the element is already visible, then `.fadeIn` doesn't do anything I believe, so the check is unnecessary (of course `.fadeIn` will do the check internally).

I don't think there is a generic solution. The approach to use depends on the specific situation.

In your example you could *split* the event handler into two and move all the code that should only be executed once into its own handler. That handler would then be removed after it was executed the first time.

```
// .one binds an event handler and removes it after the first execution
$('.clickers').one('click', function() {
    $('#some-element').fadeIn('slow'); //Slow because we're cool
}).on('click', function() {
    //do everything else
});
```

Event handlers are executed in the order they are bound, so the fade in would be triggered first.